# Visual-Studio, C#:Why I don't get a compiler error if I don't "try-catch an exception"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I try to build a simple application in Visual Studio that involves a Microsoft Access database file, but I noticed that when I am opening the connection to the database I **do not get a compile error** although I should be warned at least, because that method throws an exception.

Of course I did noticed the exception after it was thrown (piece of code with the comment bellow), during the compiling procedure.

So how am I supposed to figure out **when I shall use a try-catch block** or how at least I am going to be warned for a method which throws an exception in Visual C#?

```
namespace DBTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Accounts1.mdb";
        OleDbConnection conn;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            MessageBox.Show(conn!=null?"Connected to Database":"Didnt connected to Database", "Database:");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open(); //The exception was THROWN HERE!
            String myQuery = "select * from mode";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, conn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you point your cursor over any method, it will list you all exceptions which a method can throw.

Comment: So I must point my cursor to every method I must use?

Comment: If the compiler would now al the mistakes a developer or user could make, or a netwerk problem or anything like that resulting in an exception no application would ever compile.

Comment: you could use a shortcut : ctrl + k, ctrl + i. With practice you may not need it.

Comment: @Skemelio "So I must point my cursor to every method I must use? " -> no but you should identify problems that can occur at runtime like invalid connection strings or no connectivity and use try..catch.. to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be coming from a background of Java with its checked exceptions but not handling an exception is not a compiler error or a warning (albeit can be good practice at times). To see what exceptions are thrown, you can read the documentation of the method or hover your mouse over the method name.

Comment: No, you'll get a runtime error if an exception is thrown and you haven't handled it

Comment: @Skemelio: Just treat C# as if every exception is a RuntimeException in this regard. Java also doesn't force you to catch *every* possible exception. Furthermore, checked exceptions were/are a controversial feature which has questionable benefit in most real-world applications (many style guides advocate for just wrapping checked exceptions in RuntimeExceptions for that very purpose).

Answer (score 0):

That’s a runtime exception so the compiler can’t help you with catching it at a compile time. And the `try-catch` block helps you to **handle** this exception, not to prevent it from being thrown at the runtime. If you don’t make a try-catch block it will be handled at a general application level.

A quote from MSDN:

> When an exception is thrown, the common language runtime (CLR) looks
>   for the catch statement that handles this exception. If the currently
>   executing method does not contain such a catch block, the CLR looks at
>   the method that called the current method, and so on up the call
>   stack. If no catch block is found, then the CLR displays an unhandled
>   exception message to the user and stops execution of the program.

Please refer to the [MSDN try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) for more information.